# How to extend a row in a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv, stream

I'm maintaining an app that exports CSV files from a multi-file database. The database's design has changed so that the set of columns of an exported table might be appended in each new file of the db. (i.e. db_file0.db has columns 'Header1', 'Header2'; and db_file1.db has columns 'Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3') The order of the columns never changes, so I don't have to worry about data entries moving around within rows.

I want to update the CSV export function so it changes the header row in the file whenever the db's columns change. I slapped together this example of how I can do so, but I'm worried that the `new_file.write(old_file.read())` line will use way too much memory on a very large CSV file.

```
import csv
import io

def update_headers(file, new_headers: list, dialect=None):

    new_file = io.StringIO()

    # Copy source file to buffer, changing header row first
    with open(file) as old_file:
        if dialect is None:
            dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(old_file.read(1024))
            old_file.seek(io.SEEK_SET)  # Sniffer moves file position; reset to 0

        r = csv.reader(old_file, dialect=dialect)
        w = csv.writer(new_file, dialect=dialect)
        w.writerow(next(r) + new_headers)
        new_file.write(old_file.read())

    # Overwrite source file with content of buffer
    with open(file, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_file.write(new_file.getvalue())

    new_file.close()
```

Is there a more memory-efficient way to transfer the bulk of the file into and out of the stream? Or is there a way to modify the file on disk without streaming it all into memory first?

Comment: user for-loop to read only line/row (or `read(1024)`) to memory  and write it in new file. There is no method to modify file without using memory.

Comment: I'll need an intermediate file on disk then, won't I? Or I'll have to spool the old file into a new file (changing the headers on the fly) and then do some renaming on disk to replace the old file.